# ¿Comó insertar inputs dinamicos y obtener sus valores?

Tags: php, html, html5

Hola chicos lo que quiero realizar es un form que cree una lista de textbox para llenar un arreglo de n posiciones desde codigo php pero no puedo capturar los nombres de los textbox que se insertan con el echo en el html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Arrays</title>
</head>

<body>
<form name="MyForm" action="" method ="POST">
<?php
  for ($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
  {
    echo "<input type='text' name='val[$i]'/>";
  }
    echo "<input type='submit' name='doAction' value='Send'/>";

  if (isset($_POST['val[1]'])) // ERROR
  { 
    echo 'OK';
  }
?>
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Tendrías que ponerlos así mejor: `<form> echo "<input type='text' name='val_$i'/>"; //</form>`
 Y luego los recuperas así: `if (isset($_POST['val_1'])) ...`  El uso de `[]` en los elementos, sería para guardar un array en ellos, y no es el caso aquí. También, el `isset` **debería estar fuera del `form`, no dentro de él.**

Comment: @A.Cedano No estoy deacuerdo con tigo, se pueden generar arrays directamente desde formularios, tal y como esta haciendo el OP, de hecho para estos caso es lo recomendable, ya que sera mucho mas facil recorrer los valores, mas aun cuando el numero de campos es dinamico.

Comment: @Xerif ¿cuál sería la diferencia, puesto que, como se ve en el código el OP genera una `input` por cada elemento dentro del array? ¿qué sentido tendría, además de tener un `input` por cada elemento del array, hacer que el `name` de ese `input` contenta a su vez **otro** array? Si te fijas bien en el código él tiene esto: `name='val[$i]` , ¿qué sentido tendría tener `n` inputs con valores como `name='val[1]', name='val[2]', name='val[n]' ...`?

Comment: @A.Cedano Desde luego que tiene mucho mas sentido `name='val[n]'` o `name='val[]'` que `name='val_$i'`, `name='val_N'`. Desconozco la finalidad concreta del OP, pero basta con observar el codigo a la hora de procesar el formulario, si utilizas `name='val_N'` ¿sera facil determiar cuantas variables `$_POST['val_*']` llegaran para procesar? Creeme, sera un dolor de cabeza y un codigo feo. Es mas simple en el primer caso hacer un `count($_POST['val'])` o recorrer sus valores con un bucle, independientemente de que tengas 1 ó 500. Los casos mas tipicos de uso suele ser con `checkbox`.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estas accediendo mal al array `val[]` has de pensar que al utilizar array en los name de un formulario en php nos generara un array en en php.

Me explico, el folmulario que muestras genera el siguiente array en `$_POST`:

```
// print_r($_POST);
Array
(
    [val] => Array
        (
            [0] => valor indice 0
            [1] => valor indice 1
            [2] => valor indice 2
            [3] => valor indice 3
            [4] => valor indice 4
            [5] => valor indice 5
            [6] => valor indice 6
            [7] => valor indice 7
            [8] => valor indice 8
            [9] => valor indice 9
        )

    [doAction] => Send
)
```

Por lo tanto

```
// Esta NO es la forma correcta de acceder al indice 1 del array val
if (isset($_POST['val[1]'])) // ERROR
{ 
  echo 'OK';
}

// Debes acceder como a cualquier otro array, tambien seria bueno asegurarnos de que val es un array
if (isset($_POST['val']) AND is_array($_POST['val'])) { 
  echo 'OK';
  // acceder a la primera posicion de val
  echo $_POST['val'][0];

  // tambien puedes utilizar un foreach para recorrer todos los campos de val
  foreach($_POST['val'] as $key => $value) {
    echo 'Clave de val: '.$key.', valor: '.$value.'\n'; 
  }
}
```